# pointing wrong list member

Tags: c, list, pointers

it may be a nooby question, but can you explain me why running this i get printed the last member of the list instead of the first? am i missing something?

```
struct nodo {
int info;
struct nodo *prec;
struct nodo *succ;
} ;
typedef struct nodo nodo;



    nodo *leggi_lista(void);

 int main (void) {

struct nodo *q;

q= NULL;
q=leggi_lista();

printf("%d\n\n", q->info);   //should print first member of the list

return 0;

}

nodo *leggi_lista(void) {       //creating list 
    nodo *p, *primo=NULL;
    int i, n;
    printf("Numero di elementi: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Inserisci %d numeri: ", n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            scanf("%d", &p->info);
            p->succ = primo;
            primo = p;
            }


    return (primo) ;}
```

aaand i dunno what else i can add the post helper is bullying me :(

Comment: Please take your time to format the code properly, it's not your first question, it's very unpleasant to read your code, format it and I could try to help you.

Comment: Get a pen and paper and draw on paper what is happening on each iteration in your loop within `leggi_lista()` function. Or use debugger ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `primo` from the function which holds the value in `p` and this is got by the last `malloc()` and obviously you see the last value being printed out.

You need to fix your function to create the list. You need to keep your list's head intact and return the `head` from the function and print from `head` to end of list.

Comment: Oh Gopi, I will give an upvote for your huge effort in finding that, this OP should learn to post readable code, as many others should.

Comment: Sorry guys next time i'll post a code more readable than this, btw ty for help :) @iharob